# JavaMail Connect over imaps to an e-mail store - extend the timeout

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, exchange-server, imap

I'm trying to extend the timeout for connecting to an e-mail store (Microsoft Exchange server) but not having success. The reason being, on my local machine connecting to the store is almost instantaneous but on the machine I'm deploying the code to it can take up to a couple minutes. Rather than continually trying to connect over and over I'd rather just have a really long timeout. How to do this? Here is my code (trying to set the timeout to 2 minutes):

```
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        properties.put("mail.imaps.host", IESProperties.STORE_HOST);
        properties.put("mail.imaps.port", "993");
        properties.put("mail.imaps.connectiontimeout", "120000"); // 2 minutes
        properties.put("mail.imaps.timeout", "120000"); // 2 minutes

        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties);
        IMAPStore store = null;

        try {
            store = (IMAPStore) session.getStore("imaps");
            try {
                store.connect(IESProperties.STORE_USERNAME, IESProperties.STORE_PASSWORD);
```

When I run this it seems to give up after only about 10 seconds or something like that.

```
jvm 1    | javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection timed out: connect;
jvm 1    |   nested exception is:
jvm 1    |      java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
jvm 1    |      at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:66
5)
jvm 1    |      at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
jvm 1    |      at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
jvm 1    |      at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:196)
jvm 1    |      at com.axa.ets.ies.Main.start(Main.java:297)
jvm 1    |      at com.axa.ets.ies.Main.main(Main.java:232)
jvm 1    |      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Sourc
e)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimple
App.java:325)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

When I telnet to the store it takes a really long time, but usually connects in about a minute.

How to extend this timeout using the API? Thanks

Comment: Set the **System** property `mail.socket.debug` to `true`, enable [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug), and verify that it's getting the correct connection timeout.  There also may be more information about the connection failure.  What JDK are you using on what OS?  What JavaMail version?  JavaMail just passes the timeout value to the JDK, which passes it to the OS.

Comment: @Bill Shannon It's definitely a timeout issue, no need to debug. I'm able to connect on several other machines with the same code and same information. I just implemented a solution that continually tries to reconnect and it succeeds eventually. It's consistent with the telnet behavior. I think I'm just gonna go ahead with continually trying to reconnect since it doesn't look like there is a code solution.

Comment: I'm just gonna request the code gets moved to another server since it appears to be some kind of lag issue with the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´m not sure if you can control that via your code. However it might be possible to control that via server (see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998665(v=exchg.150).aspx) -> connection time-out limits for IMAP4):

*This example sets the connection time-out limit for idle authenticated connections.*

```
Set-ImapSettings -Identity CAS01 -AuthenticatedConnectionTimeout TimeValue
```

*This example sets the connection time-out limit for idle unauthenticated connections.*

```
Set-ImapSettings -Identity CAS01 -PreAuthenticatedConnectionTimeout TimeValue
```

Comment: Yea I don't think this is an option I definitely don't wanna change the server because it's used by a lot of people.

Comment: I've requested a different server to deploy the code to since everywhere else it connects instantly. Since this could conceivably be a solution for some people I'll mark it as the correct answer.